# correctly implement backbone comparators

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm getting a bit stuck implemented a backbone comparator, I basically want to select different sorting methods based on the route and use the comparator to sort the collection.  Ideally I want to keep the sorting logic encapsulated within the collection but seem to be getting stuck.   For example

```
    Requests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Request,
        comparator : function(ab) {
            return -ab.id;
        },          
        nooffers : function() {
            return this.sortBy(function(ab) {               
                 return ab.get('offers');
            });
        }
    });
```

So by default it sorts based on the default comparator - but in my routing I wish to be able to resort e.g. do something like

```
   routes : {
        "" : "index",
        '/ordering/:order' : 'ordering'
    },
    ordering : function(theorder) {
        ordering = theorder;
        if(theorder == 'nooffers') {
            Request.comparator = Request.nooffers();
        }
        Request.sort();
        listView.render();  
        howitworksView.render();
    }
```

However in that case I get an error ('c.call is not a function') any ideas?

Comment: The answer was good but the question deserved some love too (for eliciting the answer.) :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have a few things wrong here.

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if(theorder == 'nooffers') {
    Request.comparator = Request.nooffers();
}
```

That executes the `nooffers` method and assigns its result to `Request.comparator`. But [`sortBy`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy) returns the sorted list:

```
nooffers : function() {
    return this.sortBy(function(ab) {               
        return ab.get('offers');
    });
}
```

and setting that list as the comparator function doesn't do anything useful.

You want to change the assignment to use the function rather that its return value:

```
if(theorder == 'nooffers') {
    Request.comparator = Request.nooffers;
}
```

and change the function to be a valid comparator function:

```
nooffers : function(ab) {
    return ab.get('offers');
}
```

Demo (run with your console open): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AAZCa/

But having someone from the outside fiddling with the collection's methods like that smells bad and you shouldn't do it. Instead, you should ask the collection to change its ordering with something like this:

```
var Requests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Request,
    comparator: function(ab) {
        if(this._order_by == 'offers')
            return ab.get('offers');
        else if(this._order_by == 'id')
            return -ab.id;
        //...
    },
    order_by_offers: function() {
        this._order_by = 'offers';
        this.sort();
    },
    order_by_default: function() {
        this._order_by = 'id';
        this.sort();
    },
    _order_by: 'id'
});
//...
rs.order_by_offers();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uM9av/

Or you could let the collection swap its own `comparator` to avoid all the conditional logic inside the `comparator`:

```
var Requests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Request,
    initialize: function() {
        this._order_by_id = this.comparator;
    },
    comparator: function(ab) {
        return -ab.id;
    },
    order_by_offers: function() {
        this.comparator = this._order_by_offers;
        this.sort();
    },
    order_by_default: function() {
        this.comparator = this._order_by_id;
        this.sort();
    },
    _order_by_offers: function(ab) {
        return ab.get('offers');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Pjfq2/

Comment: @ggozad: Thanks. I like to teach people how to avoid bugs as well as help them fix their current bugs. And http://jsfiddle.net/ takes a lot of the effort away.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate the time you have taken to explain all of this!

Comment: @muistooshort Your JSFiddles no longer work because the Backbone they provide appears to no longer be at the given URL. How would this work, anyway? Shouldn't you be changing the `comparator` on the `Requests` for the collection rather than `Request` for a single model? No matter what I do, though, I cannot change the `comparator` after it is set in the collection definition.

Comment: @muistooshort I have [a fork of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/enderandpeter/tesr896L/) with Backbone and Underscore from another CDN. I have confirmed that this and other examples do sort the collection, but I was working with Udacity's ToDo MVC example where the collection has an `addAll` method which clears the list and repopulates it based on the current sorting. That is what I needed to call, in addition to `sort()`. I have this working now in [my version of ToDo example](https://github.com/enderandpeter/ud989-todo-app/tree/js-design-patterns).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote custom method in the collection which will take care of sorting both ascending and descending and also it also sorts records with alphanumeric appropriately

```
var LetterVariables = Backbone.Collection.extend({



    initialize: function (id) {

        //id of the table
        this.id = id;

        this.sortVar = "id"; //default sorting column
        this.sOrder = "asc" //default sort order
    },
    //comparator function that will create a descending and an ascending order tot he view
    comparator: function (item,itemb) {
        var a=item.get(this.sortVar);
        var b=itemb.get(this.sortVar);
        if (this.sOrder == "asc") {
            return this.SortCustom(a, b);
        }
        return -this.SortCustom(a, b);
    },
    SortCustom:function(a,b){
                if (isNaN(a)) {
                    if (isNaN(b)) {
                        if (a > b) return 1; // before
                        if (b > a) return -1; // after
                        return 0;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
                if (isNaN(b)) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (+a > +b) return 1; // before
                if (+b > +a) return -1; // after
                return 0;
    },
    Sort: function (by, order) {

        this.sOrder = order;
        this.sortVar = by;
        this.sort();
    }});
```

//you can sort by using the "Sort" method (look closely uppercase S for Sort method)