# how to sort backbone models/views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What is the basic way to keep models any views in order using Backbone? I have some idea but it's not totally clear.

I want to keep them in order by a field called "created_at". I know there is the ability to provier a comparator function in the collection but I'm not sure how it works.

I also want this order in the collection to be reflected by the views at all times (in a list). I'm not exactly sure where I tie into the model though. I'm guessing i look for change in an index attribute and then update a  to match?

Thanks very much for any help or explanation!

Comment: See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431171/correctly-implement-backbone-comparators).

Answer (score 4):

When you define your collection, you also define comparators.
I did it this way recently:

```
        comparators: {
            id: function(animal) {
              return Number(animal.get("id"));
            },

            d_id: function(animal) {
              return -Number(animal.get("id")); // descending
            },

            name: function(animal) {
              return animal.get("name");
            },

            d_name: function(animal) {
              return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, _.map(animal.get("name").split(""), function (c) {
                    return 0xffff - c.charCodeAt();
                    })
              );
            },
        }
```

these I defined within my collection code.

Then, in rendering my collection views, I just did this
(this  was within my view that renders the whole collection, in `initialize()`:

```
this.collection = new MyCollection();
this.collection.comparator = Collection.comparators[// here I put 'id' or 'd_id' etc. ];
this.collection.sort();
```

Since this code is in your views's initialize, you can define your comparator 
when you initialize your view, and pass it a name of a comparator like this:

```
var directory = new pageView("d_id");
```

and than thru `initialize(comparator_id)` you could pass this to your code in initialize:

```
this.collection = new MyCollection();
this.collection.comparator = Collection.comparators[comparator_id];
this.collection.sort();
```

And then I can use the collection in rendering and re-rendering the view/page

Edited:

Here is [Backbone's collection.comparator](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator) documentation, 
And right below it is an explanation of `sort()`

Basically, comparator can be a property of a model or a function that returns a property, 
Or a negative property, if it's numeric, for descending order, 
or a string or its reverse value for descending order
like in the example I gave you here.

So, comparator returns a property like "id" or "name", or "-id" , "-name" etc etc.
(for string you can't just make it "negative", you need to apply more complex function,
as I wrote.)

Comment: To toninoj:
I did the similiar thing in my code, and it works fine normally, but for latest chrome, If I refresh the list twice in a short time, the result will be reversed as my comparator. not sure it's designed like this or bugs.