# Defining Multiple Comparators for Sorting and Reverse Sorting Appcelerator Backbone Models

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, model, appcelerator, comparator

I am defining an Appcelerator DataGrid in the new Alloy implementation, which relies on the Backbone framework. I have successfully implemented a horizontally and vertically scrolling DataGrid, which also databinds data collections to the DataGrid via REST queries, and allows the user to sort the grid when touching column headers.

The one issue I have encountered is this.  When implementing the data model using the Backbone model implementation, and I use the comparator to sort the data model in an ascending fashion.  I have also extended the model to allow the user to define the sort criteria (passing a column definition for the filter).

Here is the question.  I know when the grid is sorted in ascending order.  Is it possible in a Backbone model to define a second comparator which will then sort in reverse order so if the user resorts I can sort in descending order (essentially creating two comparators)?  I have seen questions about reverse sorting, but nothing about allowing two comparator options in one model.

A generic model I am following for Appcelerator is their example:

```
exports.definition = {

config : {
    // table schema and adapter information
},

extendModel: function(Model) {      
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        // Extend, override or implement the Backbone.Model methods                     
    });
    return Model;
},

extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {

        // Implement the comparator method.
        comparator : function(book) {
            return book.get('title');
        }

    }); // end extend

    return Collection;
}
```

}

with the above in mind then, I would just like the second access to the comparator to essentially reverse sort the titles, if possible.

Thanks for any guidance.

Chris.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9431171/479863 ?

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js/#21434708

Answer (score 0):

To sort in descending order for strings(case insensitive) or just numbers, try this:

```
var sort_descending = false; /* assuming you are able to set this variable when you need to sort */
var sort_attribute_name = "title"; /* assuming you can set the attribute name on which you want to sort */
book_list.comparator = function(book){ /* book_list is an instance of book_collection */
  if(sort_descending){
    if(isNaN(book.get(sort_attribute_name)){
       var str = book.get(sort_attribute_name);
       str = str.toLowerCase();
       str = str.split("");
       str = _.map(str, function(letter){
          return String.fromCharCode(-(letter.charCodeAt(0))); /* from an SO answer*/
       });
    }
    return -book.get(sort_attribute_name);
  }
  return book.get(sort_attribute_name);
};
```