# How to override or change comparator on backbone collection?

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, comparator

I have a backbone collection called `Topics` that in one instance in my app I would like sorted by a property I have called `view_count`.

Another instance of the `Topics` collection I want to be sorted by `name` alphabetically.

Currently, on the collection, I have a comparator:

```
  comparator: (topic) -> 
     return topic.get('view_count') * -1
```

When I want the collection to be sorted by `name` rather than `view_count`, what is an elegant way to override or change the comparator/sorting options? I have tried to declare the comparator function on each initialization of the Topics collection bu that doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: Similar question has been answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431171/correctly-implement-backbone-comparators) . Hope it will also be helpful for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your collection to:

```
var Topics = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.sortProperty = options.sortProperty;
  },
  comparator: function(topic) {
    if(this.sortProperty == "view_count")
      return topic.get("view_count") * -1;
    else
      return topic.get("name");
  }      
});
```

then when you instantiate your collection:

```
var topics1 = new Topics({sortProperty : "view_count"});
var topics2 = new Topics({sortProperty : "name"});
```

You can also change the sorting property after initializing a collection using:

```
topics1.sortProperty = "name";
```

Comment: What happens when you multiply a string by `-1`?

Comment: Why do you assume it's a string? The property name is a String for sure, but the actual model property could be of any value. It's up to the OP to decide how to do the actual sorting once he knows the value of sortBy. He can use if/else to further customize the comparator based on the value of sortBy but I think that's very obvious.

Comment: Why would you expect something called "name" to be a number? Your example code as it stands will try to multiple a name string by `-1` and that doesn't make any sense so your answer is woefully incomplete. Also, simply setting the `sortBy` property won't resort the collection.

Comment: I updated the answer in case it wasn't obvious enough how to further customize the sorting. The question wasn't about how to to do sort/resort, it was about how to determine what model property to use in the sorting.

Comment: I also renamed sortBy to sortProperty, not to confuse it with backbone's sortBy. This is meant to be a custom property.